# Jenkins sees changes in two branches, but runs only one build

Tags: jenkins

I am using the "inverse" build strategy. When we do a merge from feature branch to development branch, then from development branch to release branch. We can see Jenkins did see the changes in the branch, but started only one build. It's not starting the build for origin/REL-Sprint1606. There is line shows Label=[origin/REL-Sprint1606]

```
Checking out Revision b81dd73053889e753b41565a4ecec99c081eb1b0 (origin/development, origin/REL-Sprint1606)
Regular expression run condition: Expression=[.*\/[dD][eE][vV].*], Label=[origin/development ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this bug report to Jenkins, but it's closed now: 
Git plugin only triggers a build for one branch
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-11337